# For Loop Escaping Discord.NET

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to code a weapon storage system for a bot that helps with tabletop RPGs, and the below function is what I'm using to try to get Input. For some reason, the foreach(var key in keys) {...} function only iterates once, and doesn't even hit the await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Done!"); directly after it. I have no idea why, and putting a bunch of breakpoints throughout the code hasn't helped either.

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetWeaponInput(SocketCommandContext context)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Name", "" },
        {"Damage Dice", "" },
        {"Damage Type", "" },
        {"Misc. Effects", "" }
    };
    var msg = await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(null, false, buildWeaponEmbed(fields, context.User));
    foreach (var key in fields.Keys)
    {
        var askingMsg = await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Please enter the Weapon's {key}.");
        var nextMsg = await NextMessageAsync(true);
        fields[key] = nextMsg.Content;
    }
    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Done!");
    await msg.ModifyAsync(x =>
    {
        x.Embed = buildWeaponEmbed(fields, context.User);
    });

    return fields;
}
```

When going through with break points, it iterates once through the loop, checks the keyword 'in' right before fields.Keys, and then just stops, eventually hitting the Client_Log event. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do these two  var askingMsg = await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Please enter the Weapon's {key}.");
            var nextMsg = await NextMessageAsync(true); reach completion?

Comment: Yeah, they are completed just fine, and the loop completes correctly the first time. I even had statements at the end of the loop that called DeleteAsync() for both messages, which also ran completely fine, but I ended up removing those (which didn't change anything)

Comment: "and doesn't even hit the Console.WriteLine("Done!"); directly after it." - there is no such statement in the code you've posted. Perhaps the problem is that you're calling this method but not awaiting the returned task? It's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: Apologies, rather than Console.WriteLine(...) I meant to talk about the line that says ```await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Done!");```
This line is never reached, the for loop iterates once and somehow escapes

Comment: If it's simply exiting then it's throwing an exception (which should  be shown in the client log event). Find the exception and you will be one step closer to solving your problem.